# Getting response with status: 405. Method not allowed for URL with POST in Firebase

Tags: typescript, post, firebase, https, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to POST some data to my Firebase database with REST API. However, I keep getting the error: `response with status: 405. Method not allowed for URL: https://myurl.firebaseio.com/data`

This is how I use the POST request:

```
createNewRoute(route){
        var url;
        var data = {
                    RouteStartAddress: route.startAddress,
                    RouteEndAddress : route.endAddress,
                    RouteStartCord: route.startCord,
                    RouteEndCord: route.endCord,
                    DepatureDateTime: route.depatureDateTime,
                    Seats: route.seats,
                    Note: route.note,
                    IsActive: true,
                    DriverSId: route.userId,
                    TimeToDist: route.timeToDist,
                    MetersToDist: route.metersToDist

        };
        url = this.routeUrl;
        var response = this.http.post(url, data).map(res => res.json());
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To write to Firebase Database using REST, the URL must end in `.json`. So:

```
url = this.routeUrl + ".json";
```

From the [relevant Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start):

> We can use any Firebase Realtime Database URL as a REST endpoint. All we need to do is append `.json` to the end of the URL and send a request from our favorite HTTPS client.